# Using internal sun classes with javac

Tags: java, javac, internal

Is there a way to disable restrictions of javac 1.6.0_22 that prevent me from using JRE internal classes like `sun.awt.event.*` ?

I'm **not** looking for:

1. an explanation why it is forbidden.
2. suggestion to use different classes
3. suggestion to use reflection
4. suggestion to use ecj/eclipse

I just want to know if it is possible or not, and if it is then how.

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? I can compile against `sun.awt.*` just fine with javac 1.6.0_22 (on the Mac, though).

Comment: I'm doing some experiments with Swing/AWT and have to access their internals.

Comment: The same issue applies to other classes like SOAP implementations in com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.* and the same ignore.symbol.file trick (top answer below) is a work-around. Adding this comment here to help folks searching for this problem in that context.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I have found the answer myself.

When javac is compiling code it doesn't link against `rt.jar` by default.
Instead it uses special symbol file `lib/ct.sym` with class stubs.

Surprisingly this file contains many but not all of internal sun classes.
In my case one of those more-internal-than-usual classes was `sun.awt.event.IgnorePaintEvent`.

And the answer to my question is: `javac -XDignore.symbol.file`

That's what javac uses for compiling `rt.jar`.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, was trying to compile but I was getting this error `package sun.nio.fs does not exist` for  `sun.nio.fs.BasicFileAttributesHolder`

Comment: Also see @karmakaze answer for additional workaround for Maven compiler plugin.

Comment: How to add this through command prompt ? i need to apply it for my web app deployed in tomcat under linux

Comment: @SanKrish - What part of `javac -XDignore.symbol.file` do you not understand?

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for your reply. i just wanted to config the `javac -XDignore.symbol.file` for tomcat instead for a class

Comment: The problem is i dont use any build tools manually . just use eclipse to build. so is it possible to configure the property for an environment ?

Comment: So why did you say you wanted to turn off the warning for >>Tomcat<< and for the command line??  You are really not making much sense ...

Comment: Anyhow, the answer make Eclipse suppress those errors / warnings is to update the compiler preferences: in the Eclipse "Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings" preference page.

Comment: Thanks . Can you please elaborate ? What to add there ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82945/discussion-between-san-krish-and-stephen-c).

Comment: @StephenC Thanks ! Can you please have a look at issue mentioned in chat and provide your suggestion on it

Comment: Yea ... well that is a consequence using a proprietary / internal `com.sun.*` class that was available in one version of Java and not another.  The best solution is to stop using that class; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes

Answer (score 42):

In addition to the answer by @marcin-wisnicki if you're using Maven, [note that the compiler plugin will silently drop any -XD flags](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs), unless you also specify
`<fork>true</fork>`: e.g.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
            ...
```

Comment: How to add this through command prompt ? i need to apply it for my web app deployed in tomcat under linux

Comment: Man, you saved my day with this! Thanks :)

Comment: @Anakin001 glad to hear it. These obscure hits are the ones I really like getting used.

Comment: Can you please tell me which plugin I can add for the ivy.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better solution. First add the option to javac `-XDenableSunApiLintControl` and then use `@SupressWarnings("sunapi")` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gradle, you need to use these options

```
compileJava {
    // enable using internal libraries
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
    options.compilerArgs << '-XDignore.symbol.file' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this only produces a Warning message; e.g.

```
[javac] /media/disk/opensso2/opensso/products/federation/openfm/source/com/sun/identity/wss/xmlsig/WSSSignatureProvider.java:46: warning: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathAPI is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[javac] import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathAPI;
```

Perhaps you have told the Java compiler to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: How to add this through command prompt ? i need to apply it for my web app deployed in tomcat under linux

Answer (score 0):

Another way is change jdk.

In my case project java version 1.8. I used from  jdk 11. Therefore This error has found in my project. So I changed my jdk from 11 to 1.8. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70471462/372019) by [@kamiel-ahmadpour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3344049/kamiel-ahmadpour): I had to set the `javaHome` when running Gradle's compile tasks via IntelliJ. My config now looks like this written in Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.isFork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = "javac"
    options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(System.getProperty("java.home"))
    options.compilerArgs.add("-XDignore.symbol.file")
}
```

Without the `javaHome` the build would fail with errors like:

```
... error: package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                            ^
```

Running Gradle tasks from the terminal doesn't need the explicitly configured `javaHome` and I didn't find the actual cause for the different behaviour, yet.

Environment:

- Java 8
- Gradle 7.5.1
- IntelliJ 2022.2.3

Answer (score 0):

In case of Ant building, add arg into javac:

```
<javac>
<compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file" />
</javac>
```