# Ant java task can't find class in rt.jar but java from console succeeds (and JAVA_HOME is properly set)

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to execute some JAX-WS code with Ant and although the **javac** target succeeds the **java** target fails with the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

Now if I explicitly add the following **jar** to the classpath used by the **java** task:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

... the execution then succeeds but that shouldn't have been necessary as **JAVA_HOME** is properly set:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

Moreover, I echo the version of **java** Ant is using and I get:

```
ant.java.version=1.7
```

Here's the relative section of my Ant ***run*** task:

```
<echo message="ant.java.version=${ant.java.version}" />
<java classname="${project.MainClass.name}">                    
   <classpath refid="run.classpath"/>           
</java>
```

Finally, if I run the code from the command line (not from within Ant) execution also succeeds without having to explicit add **rt.jar** to the **CLASSPATH**.

## update and resolution

Looking at the accepted answer I think this is an instance of a broader class of problems related to using internal Sun classes. As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4070685/274677), to explicitly compile against the internal Sun classes one has to set the `javac -XDignore.symbol.file` flag. This is because `javac` does not by default link against the `rt.jar` file but rather against a special symbol file `lib/ct.sym` with class stubs that contains many (but not all) of Sun's classes. Explicitly adding `rt.jar` in the classpath also solves the problem for the exact same reason but I think it's cleaner to use `javac -XDignore.symbol.file`. As to why Ant apparently compiles against `rt.jar` when `fork` is set to true (as suggested [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428695/274677)), I still don't know.

In retrospect I think it makes sense that `javac` doesn't include `rt.jar` in the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add compiler argument:

```
<compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file" />
```

This worked for me:

```
 <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build_output" source="1.7" target="1.7">
  <compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file" />
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="lib/......jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/....jar"/>
  </classpath>
</javac>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution was to set the **java**'s Ant task **fork** property to "true":

```
<java classname ="${project.MainClass.name}" fork="true">
    <classpath refid="run.classpath"/>
</java>
```

When **fork** is set to "true" then the rt.jar doesn't have to be explicitly present in the *run.classpath*.