# NoClassDefFoundError using sun.misc.Unsafe

Tags: java

I get the following exception when calling Unsafe.putInt:

```
A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: java/lang/InvalidClassException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/InvalidClassException
```

Unsafe lives in rt.jar, but I am unable to find java/lang/InvalidClassException, only java.io.InvalidClassException.

How do I resolve this exception? (if it matters, I'm using jdk 1.7u55)

Thank you for any help.

Update: this is caused by a call to the native method unsafe.arrayBaseOffset. I can work around it by using the static variables: ARRAY_?_BASE_OFFSET, but I don't know why.

Comment: Are you having this problem at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Could this be your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac/4070685#4070685

Comment: Look at your error message. That's not the same class.