# How to properly catch ClientTransportException

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP client written with JAX-WS.
My code is something like this:

```
UpdateSub port = service.getUpdateSub();
port.soapMethod(parameter);
```

I want to have specific code for the case when the connection to the SOAP server is refused or when it is timed out.
I tested these cases and I see that the soapMethod throws a ClientTransportException.
The ClientTransportException is from a sun package, so if I import it in order to catch it the compiler throws this error:

> package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client does not exist

I solved this problem the way karmakaze suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac/30472473#comment59479664_30472473)

From what I understand this is only a workaround and Oracle doesn't recommend doing it. 
So, what would be the proper way of catching this kind of exception **without** compiler arguments?

Comment: Hello. I still find no easy way to handle 401 or 403 response code with JAX-WS... I would like to provide a dedicated exception when webservice credentials are invalid. Still searching

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view ClientTransportException is not designed to be caught, WebServiceException should be used instead, but then HTTP status code is no longer available.

I have investigated how to handle SOAP 1.2 Fault for invalid authentication answered by a server with HTTP 401 status code. According to [SOAP 1.2 Adjuncts](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-soap12-part2-20020626/#tabreqstatereqtrans) such an answer is perfectly valid.

The main trouble comes from [HttpTransportPipe::checkStatusCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/transport/http/client/HttpTransportPipe.java#HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode%28java.io.InputStream%2Ccom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport%29) which prevents status code other than 400 and 500 to be processed as SOAP Fault, leading to ClientTransportException, I consider it should only be thrown when payload is lacking for non supported status code, I mean codes other than those listed in standard's table 17. See related [commit comments](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxws/commit/295b98e5a5b90965902ef6f163f10ed62aa2aac0) and [original issue in tracker](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-795).

Comment: So the default implementation of SOAP 1.2 clients in the JDK literally cannot handle a server sending a 401 UNAUTHORIZED back? Despite it being a perfectly valid response? This seems insane!

Comment: Right, it made me crazy too... This answer is quite old and links are broken as project moved, so I invite you to compare with latest Java runtime  HttpTransportPipe::checkStatusCode method but I guess nothing has changed concerning 401 http error handling.