# Java - Internal package found, but subpackage is missing

Tags: java-8, xerces, sun

While using JDK internal Xerces implementation, I have the following issue:
At compile javac warns me that

```
XMLSchema.java:28: warning: XSConstants is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xs.XSConstants;
```

but fails to find `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xs.datatypes` package.

```
XMLSchema.java:35: error: package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xs.datatypes does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xs.datatypes.ObjectList;
```

What could be the issue here?

I'm using JDK 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been reported and answered before: [Using internal sun classes with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac/4070685#4070685)

When javac is compiling code it doesn't link against rt.jar by default. Instead it uses special symbol file lib/ct.sym with class stubs.

Surprisingly this file contains many but not all of internal sun classes. In my case one of those more-internal-than-usual classes was com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xs.datatypes.ObjectList (adapted answer)