# Package from rt.jar "does not exist" when compiling with ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I was trying to improve logging of my HTTP connections by using the built-in java.util.logging features. But after inserting a line to activate the logging in the code, i'm getting an error in my ant build that i do not understand.

```
error: package sun.util.logging does not exist
    import sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger;
           ^
```

`sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger` is located in rt.jar which should always be on the classpath as far as i know. And it's not an "internal API" that would throw a warning during compilation. The code works fine in Eclipse.

Ant is running on JDK 1.8.0_60 as is my Eclipse project. I expect it to use the rt.jar from that installation. Why can it not access some select classes? Or am i looking at the wrong set of core classes and the javac task is using a different rt.jar?

Sidenote: i know that i can use logging properties to set it up. That's not the point of this question. I want to know why ant is having a problem that Eclipse doesn't.

Comment: I'm starting to think that "someone" removed all the access restrictions on rt.jar in my Eclipse workspace and that i should never have been able to access `PlatformLogger` in the first place. But the question remains, how does javac know what classes may not be referenced by code?

Comment: Eclipse does not use `javac`. They have their own compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question explains my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac)

In short: javac doesn't actually compile against `rt.jar`. Instead it uses `jdk/lib/ct.sym` which contains most classes as stubs, but e.g. not PlatformLogger. There's a VM parameter to deactivate it, but that's of course not encouraged.

Eclipse on the other hand is using ct.sym as a friendly suggestion that you can throw out the window if you like to code like my co-workers.