# Using javac from java14 to generate code for java7

Tags: java, java-14

I have a class, which uses `sun.rmi` API (read below for reasons). I want to use java 14 for compilation of my project, but it should run on java 7 as well. So I try to use `javac -release 7` flag to cross-compile across versions. Alas, compilation fails with

```
error: package sun.rmi.transport does not exist
```

Is there any way to let compiler now that this is OK? :)

I develop a java agent which should instrument RMI transport via bytecode generation to pass some data along with each RMI call. So please do not tell me "you REALLY should not depend on internal APIs".

Comment: Why do you want to use JDK 14 if you target JDK 7?

Comment: @Puce I have several modules in my gradle project. Some of them target java7, some later versions. I would like to use a single compiler and just change target release on per-module basis.

Comment: Have you tried using `--add-exports java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=<my module>` ?

Comment: @JornVernee Yes: `error: option --add-exports not allowed with target 7`

Comment: @JornVernee Also, `error: package sun.rmi.transport does not exist` is not a sign of requiring an export.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac

Comment: @BrianGoetz certainly related, but that question was not helpful too :( `-XDignore.symbol.file` gives the same error

Comment: Of course, `-XDignore.symbol.file` can't work with the `-release` option, as there is no alternative to the symbol file in that case. The `-release` option specifically tells the compiler to use the symbol file to find out which API artifacts are available. But you can always extend the set of available classes by putting a jar file containing a bunch of `sun.` classes having the desired properties on the class path while compiling.

Comment: You can always use plain old `--source 7 --target 7`. This will be not fully safe but this will solve your problem. Also, you can use `--source 7 --target 7 -Xbootclasspath:path_to_jdk7\jre\lib\rt.jar` which is a safer solution.