# JAXB: specific Namespace Prefix to all the elements

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, jaxb2

I have the same problem of:

[JAXB :Need Namespace Prefix to all the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895486/jaxb-need-namespace-prefix-to-all-the-elements)

however, I have to use a specific namespace. Then I change the package-info.java to:

```
@XmlSchema(
namespace = "www.example.com/a",
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="pre", namespaceURI="www.example.com/a")})

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

I execute the example by:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, FactoryConfigurationError {
    ObjectFactory o = new ObjectFactory();
    Login l = o.createLogin();
    l.setPassword("abc");
    l.setUsername("abc");
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(l.getClass());

    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    m.marshal(l, System.out);
}
}
```

However, my result has the prefix "ns2" instead of "pre" as I set in the package-info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Login xmlns:ns2="www.example.com/a">
    <username>abc</username>
    <password>abc</password>
</ns2:Login>
```

Then I tried a shortcut, by doing:
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

```
    XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance()
             .createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
        xmlStreamWriter.setPrefix("pre", "www.example.com/a");

    m.marshal(l, xmlStreamWriter);
```

If in one hand it adds the prefix. In other hand, the name space is not included in the xml:
        abcabc

What I was expecting is some like:
    
    
        abc
        abc

UPDATE:

I could find the answer in another question:

[What happened to JAXB's NamespacePrefixMapper in JDK6u18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326107/what-happened-to-jaxbs-namespaceprefixmapper-in-jdk6u18)

I need a JABX RI. And extending the NamespacePrefixMapper and adding it to the masherller, I can generate the xml with the correct prefix.